# Replace Numbers with Sed, Change a list of number say 1 to a 1000 with may duplicate numbers But only 1 not 11 or 2 but not 22

Tags: sed, replace, numbers

I would like to change the following list of text that can thousands of lines long.

The goal is to change the NET1 to NET66 But only on the 12 lines that have Net1 but not change the NET10, NET11, NET12, NET13 or any line that have NET1### in it.

I was trying to use

```
sed -i s/NET1/NET66/g list
```

But It changed the all the lines had a NET1 in the line (NET10 changed to NET660)
Thanks for any help.

```
317NET1             1          M      A01X+004115Y+016850X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1             2                 A04X+004115Y+016850X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1                         D0160PA00X+004115Y+016850               S0                                                                                                                            
317NET1             3          M      A01X+004500Y+033650X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1             4                 A04X+004500Y+033650X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1                         D0160PA00X+004500Y+033650               S0                                                                                                                            
317NET2             5          M      A01X+004405Y+020600X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET2             6                 A04X+004405Y+020600X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET2                         D0160PA00X+004405Y+020600               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET2             7                 A01X+005010Y+020585X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET3             8          M      A01X+004405Y+021100X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET3             9                 A04X+004405Y+021100X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET3                         D0160PA00X+004405Y+021100               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET3             10                A01X+005010Y+021085X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET4             11         M      A01X+003408Y+026300X0500Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET4             12                A04X+003408Y+026300X0500Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET4                         D0340PA00X+003408Y+026300               S0             
317NET1             36                A01X+005615Y+024105X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1             37         M      A04X+005615Y+024105X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1                         D0160PA00X+005615Y+024105               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET10            38                A01X+005010Y+024085X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET10            39                A01X+012305Y+019060X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET10            40         M      A04X+012305Y+019060X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET10                        D0160PA00X+012305Y+019060               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET10            41                A01X+012620Y+018218X0120Y0720     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET10            42                A01X+013105Y+033405X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET10            43         M      A04X+013105Y+033405X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET10                        D0160PA00X+013105Y+033405               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET10            44                A01X+012505Y+033400X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET11            45                A01X+005600Y+024600X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11            46         M      A04X+005600Y+024600X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11                        D0160PA00X+005600Y+024600               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET11            47                A01X+005010Y+024585X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET11            48                A01X+002208Y+025300X0500Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11            49         M      A04X+002208Y+025300X0500Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11                        D0340PA00X+002208Y+025300               S0                                                                                                                            
317NET11            50                A01X+013105Y+033890X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11            51         M      A04X+013105Y+033890X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET11                        D0160PA00X+013105Y+033890               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET11            52                A01X+012505Y+033900X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET11            53                A01X+004505Y+018850X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1             54         M      A04X+004505Y+018850X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET1                         D0160PA00X+004505Y+018850               S0                                                                                                                            
317NET12            55         M      A01X+004365Y+025105X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET12            56                A04X+004365Y+025105X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET12                        D0160PA00X+004365Y+025105               S0                                                                                                                            
327NET1             57                A01X+005010Y+025085X0560Y0220     S0                                                                                                                            
317NET13            58         M      A01X+004365Y+025600X0280Y         S0                                                                                                                            
017NET13            59                A04X+004365Y+025600X0280Y         S0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: I was trying to use Sed -i s/NET1/NET66/g list But It changed the all the lines had a NET1 in the line (NET10 changed to NET660)

Comment: I may have figured it out with sed s/NET1[[:space:]]/NET66/g zz

Comment: Please kindly check answer below, and if it works, accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```sh
awk '{sub(/NET1$/, "NET66", $1)}1' file > outfile
```

I.e. remove `NET1` at the end of the first field and then print the record.

Or with `sed`:

```sh
sed -i 's/^\([0-9]*\)NET1\([[:space:]]\)/\1NET66\2/' file
```

`^\([0-9]*\)NET1\([[:space:]]\)` only matches `NET1` after a number at the line start and when it is followed with a whitespace character. `\1` and `\2` are placeholders that revert the captured values in the result.